# I can't seem to find the cause of this NullPointerException

Tags: java

I'm quite new to making games in Java, and this is my first project making a game.
For some reason, my code is causing a NullPointerException that I couldn't find the cause of it.

Edit: Was a very dumb mistake that caused a chain reaction it's solved now

Comment: it's at this line: sr.SThreadsController.spawnFood(SThreadsController.java:118)

Comment: Now you get to experience *debugging*, the part of programming that many new programmers don't realize exists. So what is `null` on line 118, and *why*.

Comment: See the answers to the linked Q&A for various common causes of NPEs, and guidance on how to diagnose them.

Comment: Turns out it was a very stupid mistake, I referred to the wrong class at line 20 which caused a chain reaction of null pointers. Now I got the game working again, thanks for the suggestions anyway